# search column for name is similar in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i have two tables, `Table 1` and `Table 2`

In `Table 1` there is a column called `event name`

In `Table 2` there is a column called `description`

Now the issue I'm having is I am needing to link rows together, the issue is one of the event names shows as this:

```
xyz presents: The Alphabet and Friends
```

And the description shows as

```
Alphabet and Friends
```

So the issue im having is i'm trying it like this:

```
Table2.where("description LIKE ?", "%xyz presents: The Alphabet and Friends%")
```

And the above is not finding anything as i expected, If i removed the first 3 words, it matches but i cannot trust this as a solution.

Any recommendations on how to fix this?

Comment: Why can't you "trust" that `LIKE` works as it is designed to?

Answer (score 1):

Searching with `LIKE` works as expected. It seems that you expect it to somehow know which words to ignore it it's match which it doesn't.  Why can't you just do?

```
Table2.where("description LIKE ?", "%The Alphabet and Friends%")
```

If you need to search a few terms you could do:

```
Table2.where("description LIKE ? or description LIKE ?", 
"%The Alphabet and Friends%", "%xyz presents:%")
```